# Python - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'WrongPasswordFile'

Tags: python, исключения

У меня есть папка с исключениями для моего десктопного приложения. Они нормально импортируются в main по отдельности, но исключения не могут унаследоваться от базового(мною созданного) исключения.

Базовое исключение(WrongPasswordError):

```html
class WrongPasswordError(Exception):
    pass
```

Наследуемое исключение(к примеру PasswordLenghtError):

```html
from WrongPasswordFile import WrongPasswordError


class PasswordLengthError(WrongPasswordError):
    pass
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Ну оно сам файл с кодом не может найти. А он где лежит - в той же папке?

Comment: @CrazyElf Да, в той же папке.

Comment: Я точно не помню, возможно тогда нужно писать `from .WrongPasswordFile` или `from ./WrongPasswordFile`, там как-то хитро из текущей папки подключалось вроде. Но не уверен.